Cannot build cucumber-java8 tests due to "cannot find symbol"... "class En"
I recently forked cucumber-jvm and I'm trying to build.  Forgive me as I'm new to java development.  I get the following build failure in IntelliJ...
C:\projects\cucumber-jvm\cucumber-java8\src\test\java\io\cucumber\java8\Java8LambdaStepDefinitionMarksCorrectStackElementTest.java:115:61
java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   class En
location: class io.cucumber.java8.Java8LambdaStepDefinitionMarksCorrectStackElementTest
There seems to be a codegen step to build the language packages but I guess that's not working?  I also see many other missing symbols errors but I assume they are related to the root cause for the above error.
Thanks!

Forked cucumber-jvm
Opened cucumber-jvm in IntelliJ
Build the project

I expected it to build.

Run mvn generate-sources or click the button to generate sources in the Maven Drawer in IDEA. It is near the reload project button.

Thank you.  When I clicked on the "generate sources..." button, I got some dependency resolution errors.  It seems it is trying to find jars for version "7.18.1-SNAPSHOT" for several dependencies but cannot find them.  I searched online and cannot find any version called "7.18.1-SNAPSHOT".  Thoughts?  Sorry if this is a dumb question.

Ah. You gotta run mvn install in the root of the project the first time around. https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/main/CONTRIBUTING.md#building

And if that doesn't fix it than I don't know. You might have imported the project in the wrong way but I can't really tell based on what you've told me.

Thank you!  I can build successfully now!  Sorry again for my ignorance.

No worries. You're learning. Btw, a better place to ask questions about building the project would be https://github.com/orgs/cucumber/discussions We only just started it.
